# Issue creating featherlight gallery manually in JS with a list of hrefs: 'TypeError: c.first is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, featherlight.js

I'm attempting to create a featherlight gallery manually in Javascript, providing a list of hrefs (list of simple path strings) using:

```
$.featherlightGallery(images);
```

But upon trying this, I get

> 'TypeError: c.first is not a function. (In 'c.first()', 'c.first' is
>   undefined)' on featherlight.gallery.min.js:7:347.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass an array of hrefs to the featherlight function, it needs to be a content filter or a jquery object, per the docs:  https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/blob/master/README.md